# Вывод данных из JSON в HTML + фильтр

Tags: javascript, html, json

Имеется json

```
[{
"name":"1",
"image": "1.jpg",
"location":"1"
"url":"1.php"},
```

как вывести его в html а также фильтр по значению location

```
<div class="col-12">
  <div class="product-thumb transition">
    <div class="images">
      <a href="URL"><img src="IMAGE" title="" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
      <div class="info">
        <h4 class="title">
          <a href="URL">NAME</a></h4>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так хотели?

```js
let array = [{
  "name":"1",
  "image": "1.jpg",
  "location":"1",
  "url":"1.php"},
  {
  "name":"2",
  "image": "2.jpg",
  "location":"2",
  "url":"2.php"},
  {
  "name":"3",
  "image": "3.jpg",
  "location":"3",
  "url":"3.php"}];



array
.filter(item=> +item.location > 1) // условие для фильтра массива. Как пример location > 1
.forEach(item => { // перебор элементов отфильтрованного массива
  let elem = document.createElement("div");
  elem.innerHTML = `
          <div class="col-12">
            <div class="product-thumb transition">
              <div class="images">
                <a href="${item.url}"><img src="${item.image}" title="" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
                <div class="info">
                  <h4 class="title">
                    <a href="URL">${item.name}</a></h4>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>`;
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
})
```

**Updated:** если сам объект нужно напечатать на странице то это так

```js
let array = [{
  "name":"1",
  "image": "1.jpg",
  "location":"1",
  "url":"1.php"},
  {
  "name":"2",
  "image": "2.jpg",
  "location":"2",
  "url":"2.php"},
  {
  "name":"3",
  "image": "3.jpg",
  "location":"3",
  "url":"3.php"}];


var str = JSON.stringify(array, null, 2); 

let pre = document.createElement("pre");

pre.innerText = str;

document.body.appendChild(pre);
```

Comment: подскажите а как вывести файл json на страницу

Comment: и ещё подскажите пожалуйста как обернуть в сетку bootstrap
<div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xl-12 order-0 order-sm-1">
<div class="category">
<div class="row">текущий код
</div></div></div>

Comment: @Dozent задайте отдельно вопрос. Вам верстальшики помогут

Comment: я имел ввиду не вывод текста, а импорт файла
как например вот тут 
requestURL = 'data.json', //файл находится в той же папке, что и html-файл, который к нему обращается

Comment: посмотрите тут https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/

Comment: может я неправильно выразился, объясню точнее:
вывод json кода не в самом коде js, а с отдельного файла

Comment: И ещё подскажите как можно избавиться от let array = для вывода полноценного json файла

Comment: let array - я это загнал в переменную. А вы как хотите загоняйте значение